# How can I use an entire *column* containing regular expressions in Postgres?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, sqlite, boolean

I have the following hiccup with Postgres:

I'm trying to mass-correct the names of streets, which are delivered in all kinds of misspellings. For example I'm trying to correct a table of misspelled addresses where "Main Street" shows up in three forms - 
"main Street", "Main-Street" and "M. Street".

For this I have a table with two columns, let's call it STREGEX.

The first column is called official_street_name and contains the standard name of the street ("Main Street"). 
Column 2 contains an individual regexp for each street's name (for example "(M|m)(.|ain)(-|\s)(S|s)tr(.|eet)") designed to identify as many different spellings as possible. That last column containing the regular expressions of street names is called stregex_column and the whole table has some 13k names of streets.

So what I do in SQLITE is run the regexp column on the misspelled columns and update the formalized names.

For example, say, I want to update a table called street_correction and has two columns, "wrong_street_name" and column_2 "corrected_street_name". The first one contains misspelled street namens and the last one is null.

```sql
update street_correction
set corrected_street_name =
(select official_street_name 
from stregex where
wrong_street_name regexp '^' || stregex || '$')

                     )
```

The above code works fine in SQLITE but I've moved on to Postgres using:

```sql
update street_correction
set corrected_street_name =
(select official_street_name 
from stregex where
wrong_street_name ~* '^' || stregex_column || '$')
```

I just exchanged "regexp" (SQLITE) with "~*" (Postgres). 
Postgres returns the error:

```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean || stregex
> LINE 6: wrong_street_name ~* '^' || stregex_column || '$')
>                                  ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Or I used the command:

```sql
select * from street_correction, stregex 
where wrong_street_name ~* '^' || stregex_column || '$'
```

and it returns the error:

```
> ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text  
> LINE 2: where wrong_street_name ~* '^' || stregex_column || '$'  
>               ^  
> SQL state: 42804  
> Character: 49
```

How can I use a column containing regular expressions in Postgres? Is that boolean error solvable?

For reference:

```sql
create table stregex (official_street_name text, stregex_column text)
;
insert into stregex values
('Main Street', '(M|m)(.|ain)(-|\s)(S|s)tr(.|eet)')
;
create table street_correction (wrong_street_name text, corrected_street_name text)
;
insert into street_correction (wrong_street_name)
values
('main Street'),
('Main-Street'),
('M. Street')
;
select * from street_correction
;
select * from stregex
;
update street_correction
set corrected_street_name =
(select official_street_name 
from stregex where
wrong_street_name ~* '^' || stregex_column || '$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses:

```
update street_correction sc
    set corrected_street_name = (select s.official_street_name 
                                 from stregex s
                                 where sc.wrong_street_name ~* ('^' || s.stregex_column || '$')
                                );
```

You might also want to be careful about the subquery returning multiple values.  That would occur if multiple regular expressions matched a single bad street name.

Your code is being parsed as:

```
(sc.wrong_street_name ~* '^') || s.stregex_column || '$'
```

which is why you are getting that error.